# How to access a file kept in an Azure dev ops repository from the csproj file using file path?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, csproj

I have my C# .Net code deployed on Azure dev ops repository. There is an snk file that I have kept in a sub folder. We are trying to access this file from the csproj file in the solution. Below is the part of the code in csproj which is being used to access the snk file.

```
<PropertyGroup>
<AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>CommerceSuite\eComObjects\IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Here Commerce Suite is the name of the repository, eComObjects is a sub folder and IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk is the snk file that is inside the eComObjects folder. When the build runs, we get an error that says 'Error signing output with public key from file 'CommerceSuite\eComObjects\IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk' -- File not found.'

I tried replacing forward slashes with backward slashes, but that didn't work. To test things around, I tried putting the snk file in the CommerceSuite main folder rather than the sub folder and that worked, but that is not what my objective is. Please suggest what can be done to access the file from the sub folder. Below is the folder structure that I have.

```
[![Folder Structure][1]][1]
```

[image]

Comment: What location is your .csproj file in the folder structure?

Comment: @andyb952, it is in the C# folder, which is the first folder in the picture, not clear enough though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as i know the path to the snk file is relative to the csproj file so in your case something like ../eComObjects/IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk  (presuming the csproj file is located in the 'C#' folder)

Comment: Please correct me if I have understood wrongly. Do you wish to say that eComObjects folder should be inside the C# folder ? You are right in your assumption that csproj is inside the 'C#' folder.

Comment: Accepting your answer, since I got my issue resolved by using '..\..\..\' in the beginning, with each '..\' representing one folder level. So my final path was '..\..\..\eComObjects\IgnifyeCommerceAssembly.snk'.